# FMDB library missing in xcode 8.x

Tags: ios

ld: library not found for -lPods-Project_name-FMDB
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The above error in xcode8.1 but code successfully run in xcode 7.x versions.

Comment: add libsqlite3.0.dylib Freamwork

Comment: hmm i added the above framework but issue is not solve

Comment: Enable Bitcode = NO in Build Setting

Comment: that is also no build setting

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution of my questions.

remove the -lPods-(someCocoaPod) lines in the 'Other Linker Flags' list BUT only if $(inherited) is at the top. At first I was unsure, but the reassuring sign was that I still saw references to my cocoapods when I left the edit mode(inherited). I tested in debug and release, both of which were giving me errors, and the problem was immediately resolved

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in Xcode 8. This was resolved by opening the FMDB-watchOS Target under Pods and setting ENABLE_BITCODE to YES.